# Understanding why Euler's Formula applies to planar graphs

Tags: geometry, surfaces

I'm trying to prove that given a planar graph (by that I mean a graph where every pair of points is joined without crossings) $V-E+F = 2$.

I can prove this by induction directly on the edges except I'm trying to understand how it is true via the Euler characteristic for the sphere.

I can see that a graph can be drawn on the plane in this way if and only if it can be drawn on the sphere in this way (i.e no crossings). Just because the plane is topologically the sphere with a point removed.

Now I'm wondering if it is possible that in some way the surface formed by the graph on the sphere is homeomorphic to the sphere? In which case we would have $\chi = 2$ immediately.

Thanks

Comment: The way you phrase things, there is no question of homeomorphism - you just drew the graph on the sphere, so the result is the same sphere (now you know which points are vertices and which lie on edges, but you haven't changed any topological data). The question is whether you know that you can apply Euler's theorem without first "flattening out the faces" - you can, but it's not totally obvious that there is a homeomorphism of the sphere with a polyhedron such that the graph is sent to the $1$-skeleton of the polyhedron.

Comment: Thanks Matt, just a quick question. What do you mean by 1-skeleton?

Comment: I mean just the vertices and edges - in general, if you think of a polyhedron as being built up of pieces of various dimensions (in this setting, just dimensions $0$, $1$ and $2$ for the vertices, edges and faces), the $n$-skeleton is all the stuff of dimension at most $n$.

Comment: Okay, now I'm struggling to see why we would need such a homeomorphism to prove the result? The graph subdivides the sphere and so satisfies Euler's formula?

Comment: It depends what your statement of Euler's theorem says exactly - you need to know that the formula is insensitive to how the edges and faces are curved, so that you don't have to use a homeomorphism to straighten out your subdivision of the sphere before the formula applies. (You also need to know that two homeomorphic spaces have the same Euler characteristic).

Comment: My definition of Euler's theorem is in terms of cellular decompositions

Comment: Then that's fine - once you draw the graph on the sphere then you have one of those. I'll assemble the comments into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you draw the graph on the sphere, you don't change any topological data, you just decide which points are vertices and which lie on edges. (If you want to see this as a cellular decomposition, you could think of the inclusion of each vertex, edge and face into the sphere, or something similar depending on your precise definition of cellular decomposition, as the maps explaining how your cell complex is built.) This means there is no possibility of the result not being a sphere, and so Euler's formula applies directly.

Comment: Thanks for this! One small problem I've just realised, how do we deal with the fact that one of the faces will have a whole punctured in it when we flatten the sphere out and so this won't actually give us a cellular decomposition?